# Meteor / Blaze / Blaze-Layout - not rendering some components

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm playing around with Meteor/Blaze/Blaze-Layout, very new to all of the above, and am running into a simple but puzzling-to-me problem. The template below renders everything inside of the `<p>` tags but does not render the first `<h2>` at all.

```
<template name="blazeTest">
  <h2>
   Hello, I am a header.
  </h2>
  <p>
    Hello I am a paragraph.
    <h2>
      Hello, I am a header inside of a paragraph.
    </h2>
  </p>
</template>
```

Am I missing some detail or does anyone have any insight as to why this might be happening? Thank you for any help you can throw my way.

Comment: I just copied your code into my own project and the template was fine... have you tried to see if there are any CSS styles causing the hidden h2?

Comment: Looks like it is showing up when I use chrome's element inspector so it must be a CSS issue. Obvious in hindsight, thanks!

Comment: If I had to guess I would say that it's being rendered above what you can actually see in chrome.  Try adding some `padding-top:` to your h2 css

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `<h2>` inside of `<p>`. That html is semantically incorrect, so you can't contain `<p>` in `<h2>` or vice versa.

Some additional (a bit cloudy) information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories

And specifically about H1: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements